# Salesforce apex Inbound SOAP web service response

Tags: apex, integration, wsdl, apex-webservice

My requirement is that I have to create an inbound SOAP web service which will return a list of data based on the input parameters.
I am using wrapper classes to build the output.

```
global class Account{
        webservice string Id;
        webservice string Name;
        webservice list<SystemWrapper> Systems;
}

global class SystemWrapper{
        webservice string Id;
        webservice string Name;
        webservice string ProductLine;
        webservice string SystemRoleId;
}
```

Now i have the following questions in the response which is generated

1. How do i specify the sequence, because the client system wants the elements in the soap reponse xml in a particular sequence. Are the nodes ordered in alphabetical order automatically?
2. How do i remove the **result** node which is added automatically to the response
   for ex :

   ```
        <result>
              <Account>
                 <Id>001M000000moDXQIA2</Id>
              </Account>
        </result>
   ```
3. And each node name should be pre-pended with a namespace that is defined in the soap:Body.

Any  help is much appreciated. Thanks!

Hi Daniel
Thanks for your reply.

However i have one more question

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:cus="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/CustomerPortalIntegrationService">
```

?

There are namespaces added to the request xml -- "cus" but whereas the response xml does not have any namespace.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/CustomerPortalIntegrationService" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
```

Can we modify the WSDL such that the response has namespaces.

Comment: Hi Team, Can someone please give some directions/inputs for my above questions. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The order of the xsd:sequence elements for a complexType that you define does appear to be alphabetical. At the very least, you have no other way to control the order of the elements within the sequence.

I don't think you can remove the 'result' element from the generated *Response elements. It's part of the mechanism that if used for handling collection parameters.

There should be no need to prefix the namespace to the nodes when the `targetNamespace` is defined. That said, as long as the inbound SOAP request matches the WSDL schema it should be fine to specify the namespace on each element.